# Android left border on selected list item in list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to do something like what the Wordpress Android app is doing:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wordpress.android

I have a list view in a navigation drawer. I managed to get the background to change when the item is selected by using a selector resource. How do I make a small coloured rectangle on the left of the selected item? Like the wordpress app.

**EDIT:**

My list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_background_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you post your selector xml and resources ?

Comment: Have a look on that page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html and the Shape resource to create a drawable like you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a layer list for that, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/drawer_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/rectangle_color"
        android:left="10dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

You could, also create a 9-patch image to skip the overdraw but it's not stylable so i wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 1):

Using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="LEFT COLOR HERE"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="RIGHT COLOR HERE"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```